# dispatch_group_async performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use dispatch queues to fill an array asynchronously 
on the both cores of iPhone 5. 
I am testing the following code:

```
float res[20000]; // an array to fill

dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
float coresNumber=[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] activeProcessorCount];
for (float i=0;i<coresNumber;i++)
dispatch_group_async(group, aQueue, ^{
    for (int k = i*20000/coresNumber; k < (i+1)*20000/coresNumber; k++) {
        float acc=0;
        for (int j=0;j<10000;j++){
            acc+=sinf(j);
        }
        res[k]=acc; // fill an array using some function (sum of sines is an example)
    }
});
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Here I am actually splitting an array by two parts and fill these parts asynchronously. 
But it performs similar to simply filling the whole array in one cycle.
What can be a reason ?

Comment: Why can not you use dispatch_apply for looping using syntax :queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) {
   // add your loop code inside.
});

Comment: Tried to use dispatch_apply - performance is significantly worse. As far as I understand there is a kind of overhead every cycle.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that times runs with different numbers of simultaneous blocks:

```
const int kArraySize = 20000;
const int kSineIterations = 10000;

float res[kArraySize];
float *r = res;         // use ptr to access array from block

dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

int coresNumber=[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] activeProcessorCount];

for (int coresToUse = 1; coresToUse <= coresNumber; coresToUse++) {
    NSDate *fillStart = [NSDate date];

    if (coresToUse == 1) {
        for (int k = 0; k < kArraySize; k++) {
            float acc=0;
            for (int j=0;j<kSineIterations;j++){
                acc+=sinf(j);
            }
            r[k]=acc; // fill an array using some function (sum of sines is an example)
        }
    } else {
        for (int i=0;i<coresToUse;i++) {
            dispatch_group_async(group, aQueue, ^{
                for (int k = i*kArraySize/coresToUse; k < (i+1)*kArraySize/coresToUse; k++) {
                    float acc=0;
                    for (int j=0;j<kSineIterations;j++){
                        acc+=sinf(j);
                    }
                    r[k]=acc; // fill an array using some function (sum of sines is an example)
                }
            });
        }
        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }

    NSDate *fillFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [fillFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:fillStart];
    NSLog(@"coresToUse = %d executionTime = %f", coresToUse, executionTime);
}
```

And here's an implementation that uses dispatch_apply() instead, trying a number of different stride lengths (as suggested by the legacy [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_apply.3.html)):

```
const int kArraySize = 20000;
const int kSineIterations = 10000;
const int kMaxStride = 32;

float res[kArraySize];
float *r = res;         // use ptr to access array from block

dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

for (int stride = 1; stride <= kMaxStride; stride *= 2) {
    NSDate *fillStart = [NSDate date];

     dispatch_apply(kArraySize / stride, aQueue, ^(size_t idx) {
        for (int k = idx * stride; k < (idx + 1) * stride; k++) {
            float acc=0;
            for (int j=0;j<kSineIterations;j++){
                acc+=sinf(j);
            }
            r[k]=acc; // fill an array using some function (sum of sines is an example)
        }
     });

    NSDate *fillFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [fillFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:fillStart];
    NSLog(@"stride = %d executionTime = %f", stride, executionTime);
}
```

My test results vary from run to run, but in general the dispatch_apply() approach is simpler, and has good performance:

```
coresToUse = 1 executionTime = 7.866005
coresToUse = 2 executionTime = 4.457676
coresToUse = 3 executionTime = 3.347830
coresToUse = 4 executionTime = 2.550073
coresToUse = 5 executionTime = 2.150453
coresToUse = 6 executionTime = 1.814090
coresToUse = 7 executionTime = 1.637852
coresToUse = 8 executionTime = 1.810749
stride = 1 executionTime = 1.634940
stride = 2 executionTime = 1.990378
stride = 4 executionTime = 2.199857
stride = 8 executionTime = 2.157229
stride = 16 executionTime = 2.010102
stride = 32 executionTime = 2.451976
```

Comment: You are right. I measured performance using clock() function. It looks like that clock() counts ticks on the both cores and shouldn't be used in this case.

Comment: What exactly is different in this solution that makes it better than the code in the question? BTW `__block` is used incorrectly, the use of `malloc` appears to add nothing but the need to use `free` at some point, and integer-valued variables are declared as `float` which is never a good idea.

Comment: The main difference is accurately comparing the runtime for different levels of parallelism. Thanks for the comments, I've made corrections.

Comment: Why can n't we use dispatch_apply for looping with will take care of every loop iteration concurrently automatically based on processor cores.